# How to obtain paypal live application id

Tags: paypal

How do I obtain a PayPal Application ID in the live PayPal environment?

I followed the instructions on https://www.x.com/, but I could not find

> My Account ==> My application ==> New App

as mentioned on the PayPal developer website.

Comment: You should be able to get more informations here  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/#register

Comment: Thank you but I tried to follow the steps as I explained in the previous post but the problem I did not find "My application" link so I can post a new application.

Comment: Did you checked this too ? https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/general-support/how-do-i-submit-my-app-paypal

Comment: The only available links under my account within (x.com) are:  
My Account



 1-My Blog
 2-My Connections
 3-My Messages
 4-My Profile

Comment: Please can anyone help I would love to go live with my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting May 13th, 2013, PayPal App management for Classic APIs will no longer be available on x.com and will be migrated to developer.paypal.com. Please check back after May 16th for the new location of APP Management.

During this time, you will not have access to submit a new App or manage your existing APPs. Your current application IDs will not be impacted by migration and will be available post-migration at the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your paypal account.

First of all navigate to [developer account](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/) applications

Then click on your **App Name**. (You have created previously)

Here you will see an option to chose **Sandbox** or **Live**. click respectively to get app Credentials.